# How will ReentrantLock object created inside a method's local scope work?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, java.util.concurrent, reentrantlock

[image]

The above is a screen print from OCP 7 java se book. page 791.

My question is if a new `ReentrantLock` object is created in a method every time and locked, how would that stop two threads from running the code block in between `lock` and `unlock`? Won't the two threads create a `ReentrantLock` object each and lock it? I can imagine how this would work if `lock` object was a instance variable only instantiated once and never changed. (preferrably `final`).

Am I misunderstanding something?

I had already asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121657/what-exactly-gets-locked-when-using-apis-in-java-util-concurrent-locks) and Did not get a clear answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right creating a 'ReentrantLock' in the method itself each and every time in order to synchronise Threads on that lock does not work. There has to be a "shared" lock object.

The example in the book is maybe a bit too simplistic.

The [documentation of `ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) uses the following example:

```
class X {
   private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   // ...

   public void m() {
     lock.lock();  // block until condition holds
     try {
       // ... method body
     } finally {
       lock.unlock()
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: beginners could potentially misunderstand this. as you may notice no one pointed this out in my previous question